Incorrect Initialization of Crane Routes in Tkinter Animation
My code is designed to create a graphical user interface (GUI) application that visualizes the movement of cranes on a construction site using the concept of a pendulum to simulate the paths of these cranes, but I have problem is about some of these cranes are not starting with the first point as expected, they start with the second point.
import tkinter as tk
import math
import xlrd
class PendulumApp:
    def __init__(self, master, supply, demand, crane, tower_crane_routes):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Rotation_Traditional_Scheduling")

        self.width, self.height = 700, 700
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Center origin adjustments
        self.center_x = self.width / 2
        self.center_y = self.height / 2
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.center_x - 3, self.center_y - 3, self.center_x + 3, self.center_y + 3,
                                fill='black')
        self.canvas.create_text(self.center_x + 15, self.center_y + 15, text="(0,0)", fill='black')

        self.Tower_crane = list(crane.values())
        self.Tower_crane_routes = tower_crane_routes

        self.draw_points(supply, 'red', 'S')
        self.draw_points(demand, 'green', 'D')
        self.draw_points(crane, 'blue', 'Tc')

        self.pendulums = []
        for pivot, points in zip(self.Tower_crane, self.Tower_crane_routes):
            pendulum = self.create_pendulum(pivot, points)
            self.pendulums.append(pendulum)

        self.add_color_legend()
        self.display_coordinate_table(supply, demand, crane)
        self.animate(rotation_speed_rad_per_min=0.5, fps=30, playback_speed=20)

    def create_pendulum(self, pivot, points):
        angles = [self.calculate_angle(pivot, point) for point in points]

        current_index = 0
        next_index = 1 if len(points) > 1 else 0
        angle = angles[current_index]
        angle_increment = 0.5
        length = 60

        # Mark pivot point
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.center_x + pivot[0] - 3, self.center_y - pivot[1] - 3,
                                self.center_x + pivot[0] + 3, self.center_y - pivot[1] + 3, fill='blue')

        # Mark pendulum points
        for point in points:
            self.canvas.create_oval(self.center_x + point[0] - 3, self.center_y - point[1] - 3,
                                    self.center_x + point[0] + 3, self.center_y - point[1] + 3, fill='red')

        pendulum_line = self.canvas.create_line(
            self.center_x + pivot[0],
            self.center_y - pivot[1],
            self.center_x + pivot[0] + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle)),
            self.center_y - (pivot[1] + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))),
            width=2
        )
        pendulum = {
            "pivot": pivot,
            "points": points,
            "angles": angles,
            "current_index": current_index,
            "next_index": next_index,
            "angle": angle,
            "angle_increment": angle_increment,
            "length": length,
            "pendulum_line": pendulum_line,
            "completed": False  # Set the completed flag to False
        }

        return pendulum

    def draw_points(self, data, color, label_prefix):
        for key, (x_val, y_val) in data.items():
            x, y = x_val + self.center_x, self.center_y - y_val
            self.canvas.create_oval(x - 3, y - 3, x + 3, y + 3, fill=color, outline=color)
            label = f"{label_prefix}{key}"
            self.canvas.create_text(x + 15, y, text=label, fill=color)

    def calculate_angle(self, pivot, point):
        dx = point[0] - pivot[0]
        dy = point[1] - pivot[1]
        return math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))

    def animate(self, rotation_speed_rad_per_min=0.5, fps=30, playback_speed=20):
        conversion_factor = (rotation_speed_rad_per_min * 60) / fps

        for pendulum in self.pendulums:
            if pendulum["completed"]:
                continue

            pendulum["angle"] += pendulum["angle_increment"] * conversion_factor

            if (pendulum["angle_increment"] > 0 and pendulum["angle"] >= pendulum["angles"][pendulum["next_index"]]) \
                    or (pendulum["angle_increment"] < 0 and pendulum["angle"] <= pendulum["angles"][
                pendulum["next_index"]]):
                pendulum["angle"] = pendulum["angles"][pendulum["next_index"]]
                pendulum["current_index"] = pendulum["next_index"]
                pendulum["next_index"] = (pendulum["next_index"] + 1) % len(pendulum["points"])
                pendulum["angle_increment"] = self.calculate_increment(pendulum)

            x = self.center_x + pendulum["pivot"][0] + pendulum["length"] * math.cos(
                math.radians(pendulum["angle"]))
            y = self.center_y - (
                    pendulum["pivot"][1] + pendulum["length"] * math.sin(math.radians(pendulum["angle"])))

            self.canvas.coords(pendulum["pendulum_line"], self.center_x + pendulum["pivot"][0],
                               self.center_y - pendulum["pivot"][1], x, y)

            if pendulum["current_index"] == len(pendulum["points"]) - 1:
                pendulum["completed"] = True

        self.master.after(playback_speed, lambda: self.animate(rotation_speed_rad_per_min, fps, playback_speed))

    def wait_at_point(self, pendulum):
        pendulum["current_index"] = pendulum["next_index"]
        pendulum["next_index"] = (pendulum["next_index"] + 1) % len(pendulum["points"])
        pendulum["angle_increment"] = self.calculate_increment(pendulum)
        pendulum["waiting"] = True
        self.master.after(500, lambda: self.release_wait(pendulum))

    def release_wait(self, pendulum):
        pendulum["waiting"] = False

    def calculate_increment(self, pendulum):
        if pendulum["angles"][pendulum["next_index"]] > pendulum["angles"][pendulum["current_index"]]:
            return abs(pendulum["angle_increment"])
        else:
            return -abs(pendulum["angle_increment"])

    def add_color_legend(self):
        padding = 10
        spacing = 20
        legend_width = 100

        # Calculating the marking start position
        legend_x = self.width - legend_width - padding
        legend_y = self.height - 3 * spacing - padding

        # Supply
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(legend_x, legend_y, legend_x + 10, legend_y + 10, fill='red', outline='red')
        self.canvas.create_text(legend_x + 15, legend_y + 5, text="S: Supply (红色)", anchor="w")

        # Demand
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(legend_x, legend_y + spacing, legend_x + 10, legend_y + spacing + 10, fill='green',
                                     outline='green')
        self.canvas.create_text(legend_x + 15, legend_y + spacing + 5, text="D: Demand (绿色)", anchor="w")

        # Crane
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(legend_x, legend_y + 2 * spacing, legend_x + 10, legend_y + 2 * spacing + 10,
                                     fill='blue', outline='blue')
        self.canvas.create_text(legend_x + 15, legend_y + 2 * spacing + 5, text="Tc: Crane (蓝色)", anchor="w")

    def display_coordinate_table(self, supply, demand, crane):
        table_x, table_y = 10, 10
        row_height = 15
        categories = [('Supply', supply, 'red'), ('Demand', demand, 'green'), ('Crane', crane, 'blue')]

        for category, data, color in categories:
            self.canvas.create_text(table_x, table_y, text=category, anchor="nw", fill=color)
            table_y += row_height
            for point in data.values():
                text = f"({point[0]}, {point[1]})"
                self.canvas.create_text(table_x, table_y, text=text, anchor="nw", fill=color)
                table_y += row_height

Thanks for helping
